# Are class feature Powers At-Will Powers?

Tags: dnd-4e

I'm incredibly new to tabletop roleplaying games and D&D 4e, and I was wondering whether a featured power counts as an at will power.

I ask this question because I am trying to create a Druid character and I saw that he has the power *Wild Shape*. I wanted to be a predator Druid but then I saw that in the build it said that the class feature was *Primal Predator*. Does this mean I can't have both *Wild Shape* and *Primal Predator*, or are class features and Druid features different? Or do all Druids get *Wild Shape* along with their other powers and a class feature? Basically, are class features and the Druid's features the same?

Also, does wild shape count as an at-will power? I know this might seem like a stupid newbie question. But please try to answer it as best as possible. I am joining a D&D group and I would not like to show up and look like a idiot.

Comment: It depends on the feature. Some class features are encounter powers or otherwise limit their use. For example, "Channel Divinity" is a class feature of numerous Divine classes, and is usable on a per-encounter basis. The key takeaway is "The power's description will explicitly state this. Read the description to be sure"

Comment: I think your confusions comes from a misunderstanding. Most classes have to At-Will _attack_ powers. Wild shape is not an attack power, so it is not under this rule.

Answer (score 7):

Wild Shape is a Class Feature that every Druid has: this says so right above the power. The Primal Guardian and Primal Predator are your Primal Aspect, each with their own bonuses. These are found on page 83 of PHB2.

And yes, Wild Shape is an at-will power. In 4e, powers are color-coded: Green ones are At-Will, Red ones are Encounter (so once per encounter) and Black ones are Daily, which you can use once per day. you can also reach what kind of power it is, its types and whatever action they take in the text right under the description, which in turn is under the color-coded header.

Comment: You can only have 2 at-will powers right so does wild shape count toward your 2 at-will powers. Or because its an power all druids have does it not count toward your 2 at-will powers.

Comment: Nope, Wild Shape is a class feature and as such does not count for your daily powers. A Druid gets the following at level 1: one Primal Aspect, the Wild Shape class feature, two At-Will ppowers, one Encounter power and one Daily power. Your choices for your At-Will powers begins right below the description for Wild Shape (look for the text Level 1 At-Will Evocations). For a Druid, Powers are named Evocations and are the same thing.

Comment: Yeah, there is that slight technical distinction. It is usable at-will (per its description), which I'm sure is the core of the question. But it is not an "at-will power" because it is a class feature, not a power.

Comment: @heathenJesus No, Wild Shape is a power. In the class feature description it specifically says "You have an at-will power, *wild shape*". And later, in the Druid Powers section, it says "Each druid has the power *wild shape*".

Comment: Ahh, @DCShannon you are correct. That's what I get for not bothering to consult the books... But there seems to be some ambiguity about what specifically is a power. For example, in the Cleric class, it explicitly describes _Healing Word_ as a power, but refers to Channel Divinity as a feature. Then follows both of those up with _"The cleric has two class features that work __like__ powers: 
Channel Divinity and healing word. The Channel 
Divinity class feature encompasses multiple powers"_ (emphasis mine)